# Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

In my react native app these errors is showing after installing `react-navigation` and `react-native-gesture-handler`

> Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>   Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
>   Could not resolve project :react-native-gesture-handler.      Required by:          project :app
>   Unable to find a matching configuration of project :react-native-gesture-handler: Non e of the consumable configurations have attributes.

Comment: You need to check that the dependencies you installed have been linked properly.

Answer (score 0):

try linking `react-native-gesture-handler` to `react-native` by running this command:

```
react-native link react-native-gesture-handler
```