# Flutter - Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: flutter, gradle, onesignal

Today suddenly my app stopped working (can't build anymore), although I was able to build couple hours earlier.

the issue is that OneSignal depends on some google services which come back as forbidden, this is what I get:

```
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0).
     Required by:
         project :app > com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1
         project :app > com.google.android.gms:play-services-places-placereport:15.0.1
      > Failed to list versions for com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/google/android/gms/play-services-basement/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not get resource 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/google/android/gms/play-services-basement/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > Could not GET 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/google/android/gms/play-services-basement/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
   > Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[15.0.1,16.0.0).
     Required by:
         project :app > com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1
      > Failed to list versions for com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/google/android/gms/play-services-tasks/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not get resource 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/google/android/gms/play-services-tasks/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > Could not GET 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/google/android/gms/play-services-tasks/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
```

I had an issue before when updating flutter itself where I had to use a VPN to be able to update, is this the same thing? I searched Github issues and stack overflow questions but none fixed the issue, also compared this app to others I've built but the implementation is identical (OneSignal wise) and they seem to work fine, what could be the cause of this?

**NOTE**: I also get this issue even when using a VPN

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55056662/62576

Comment: You could try the solution from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44500176/setting-up-gradle-for-api-26-android, in particular adding the `google()` repository. Unsure which other repository adds `google.bintray.com`.

Comment: Also, given the timing, it seems likely related to https://jfrog.com/blog/into-the-sunset-bintray-jcenter-gocenter-and-chartcenter/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for everyone who commented on the question, but I saw these resources before, fortunately though, I was able to fix it by doing the following:

1- Inside build.gradle (app level), I bumped up one signal gradle from

```
classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.12.6, 0.99.99]'
```

to

```
classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:0.12.10'
```

2- Inside build.gradle (project level), I bumped up gradle from

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
```

to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3'
```

3- Inside gradle > wrapper > gradle-wrapper.properties I updated gradle from

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.2-all.zip
```

to

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-all.zip
```

4- Updated one signal package to version ^2.6.3 instead of ^2.6.1 (I don't think it did something but yeah)